# How to prevent windows authentication from redirecting the browser to the API URL?

Tags: angular, iis, asp.net-core, windows-authentication

We have an Angular4 front end which calls an ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web API hosted in IIS using Windows Authentication. Upon loading the front end for the first time or in incognito, it requires a login, but after successful login it does not redirect back to the front end. It plays out like this:

- Navigate to front end at `http://localhost:4200`
- Login prompt pops up with the API url at `http://localhost:53465`
- After successful login, the browser stays on `http://localhost:53465` instead of redirecting to `http://localhost:4200`

This all started happening recently with the newest update to Chrome, previously this was never an issue; after logging in, you would be redirected to the front-end, whatever page you intended to navigate to.

Here is what we have for web.config on the front-end site:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Here is the web.config for the API site:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="aspNetCore" />
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" startupTimeLimit="3600" requestTimeout="23:00:00" forwardWindowsAuthToken="true" />
    <security>
      <authorization>
        <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
        <add accessType="Allow" users="?" verbs="OPTIONS" />
        <add accessType="Allow" roles="USERS" />
      </authorization>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Here is how we are making our http requests in Angular:

```
getPendingRequests(owner: string): Observable<any[]> {
        let url = `${this.baseUrl}pending`;
        return this._http.get(url).map((res: Response) => res.json());
    }
```

and the options that send with it:

```
@Injectable()
export class NoCacheRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
    constructor () {
        super();
        this.headers.append('Cache-Control','no-cache');
        this.headers.append('Pragma', 'no-cache');
        this.headers.append('Expires', 'Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT');
        this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        this.withCredentials = true;
      }
}
```

Here is a sample API endpoint:

```
[Route("pending")]
[Authorize]
public class PendingCorrespondenceController : Controller
{
    ....
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetPendingCorrespondence()
        {
```

And our Startup.cs for the API:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
            services.AddMemoryCache();
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            services.AddAuthentication("CookieAuthenticationScheme")
                .AddCookie("CookieAuthenticationScheme");
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin", builder =>
                {
                    builder.WithOrigins(Configuration["CORS:AllowedOrigins"]);
                    builder.AllowCredentials();
                    builder.AllowAnyHeader();
                    builder.AllowAnyMethod();
                });
            });

            services.AddSingleton<IDashboardData, CacheDashboardData>();
            services.AddSingleton<ICorrespondencePermission, CorrespondencePermission>();
            services.AddSingleton<IPendingCorrespondence, PendingCorrespondence.PendingCorrespondence>();
            services.AddSingleton<IHoldForReview, HoldForReview.HoldForReview>();
            services.AddSingleton<IActiveDirectory, ActiveDirectory>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment()) app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");
            app.UseMiddleware<PermissionsMiddleware>();
            app.UseMiddleware<GlobalExceptionLogger>();
            app.UseMvc().UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        }
```

We have been struggling with this for a couple days with no luck, is there something obvious we are missing?

Comment: We are having the same issue with AngularJS, have you found a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately we did not find a solution and we had to resort to combining the API and the UI on the same server/port